# Android Google+ Api login doesn't work

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-play-services

I want to implement the Google+ Api into my app. Therefore I have this code:

```
private void googleLogin(){
        if(!isConnectingToInternet()){
            createInetErrorDialog();
        } else{

            mPlusClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

            if(mPlusClient != null) {
                mPlusClient.connect();
                System.out.println("GOOGLE connected");
            }

        }
    }
```

Then in onConnected I do this:

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        if(mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mPlusClient) != null) {
                Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mPlusClient);
                currentPersonName = person.getDisplayName();
                email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mPlusClient);
                System.out.println("GOOGLE onConnected" + email);
                getAccessToken();
            } else {
                System.out.println("GOOGLE error connection" + Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mPlusClient));
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it always runs into the else case because getCurrentPerson returns null. When I first started my app, the consent screen poped up and I could register, so the connection between app and google project is possible. SHA-1 fingerprints, permissions and apis are set and enabled.

The request to the AccountApi for the email is possible, but not to the PeopleApi. Can anyone help me? I tried several "solutions" but nothing worked, this null of PeopleApi

Comment: Do you have an account logged in your test device?

Comment: whats your logcat returns ??

Comment: Please follow this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Comment: yes, my test device is my mobile phone 
@IntelliJAmiya no special logcat returns, I will have a look on this link

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya mhm it looks like it is exactly what I'm doing but it does not work :( I will have one more look on the fingerprint, maybe something went wrong there, but I don't think so

Comment: Please checkout SHA1 Fingerprint section .

Comment: finally, a full uninstall seems to work now! :o don't know what the error was :/